# How to create a list of proprieties for a dialog box python blender

Tags: python, add-on

My problem is I want to create an addon that check the name of all my textures and propose to rename them.

For that i would like to create a list of properties.

like :

```
list = ['a','b','c']
propList = []
    
for e in list :
    prop[e] : bpy.props.StringProperty(name = 'Enter text', default = e)
```

then i want to use this list in the draw :

```
def draw(self, context):
    for p in propList:
        self.layout.prop(self, "p")
```

But without surprises, i can't affect a bpy.props in a list.

Do anybody have an idea please ?

Comment: What do you want? If you want to make a list to choose from, use EnumProperty

Comment: I want a list of proporties something like :
```
propList = [prop1 : bpy.props.StringProperty(), prop2 : bpy.props.StringProperty()]
```

I will check what is an EnumProperty thanks !

Comment: i want a list because i have to create as much bpy.pops.StringProperty as texture that aren't well named in the project. So it varies a lot. I first create a list of texture with all the texture that aren't well named. An user is suppose to rename it thanks to my add-on